# Sharepoint or Outlook

Tags: list, outlook, contacts

I have a SharePoint *Contact* list that contains "Customer name", "Address details", etc. which includes an appropriate **Sales Rep** for each customer. I have linked the contact list to Outlook and can see all these records.

However I need to **filter** these records by Sales Rep, so that each Sales Rep can only see their own customers in Outlook.

What would be a better choice to achieve this; SharePoint or Outlook? And how?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that **Sales Rep** is `People and Group` column, you can create a view with filter `Sales Rep = [Me]`.

So whenever **Sales Rep** comes to this view he/she will see only there records.

For reference: [The Power of [Me] in SharePoint Library Views and List Views](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/sharepoint-library-views-and-list-views/)